# Iframe not being created in correct place

Tags: javascript

I'm loading an iframe into a div on a page. If I use this it works fine:

```
<iframe src="http://myURL.com/embed/whatever/1213" id="frameID" frameBorder="0" width="100%" style="overflow:hidden"></iframe>
<script>
    window.addEventListener( "message",
        function (e) {
            var frameHeight = e.data.height;
            document.getElementById('frameID').height=frameHeight + "px";
        },
        false
    );
</script>
```

But, I'd rather a total javascript solution so I use the following, but it loads the iframe at the end of the page instead of in the div as above.

```
<script>
    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');       
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    iframe.src = 'http://myURL.com/embed/whatever/1213';       
    iframe.width = '100%';
    iframe.id = 'frameID';
    iframe.frameBorder = '0';
    iframe.style = 'overflow:hidden';
    window.addEventListener( "message",
        function (e) {
           var frameHeight = e.data.height;
           alert(frameHeight);
           document.getElementById('frameID').height=frameHeight + "px";         
        },
        false
    );
</script>
```

Why would it do that?

Answer (score 0):

By using `document.body.appendChild()` you're appending it as a child of `body`.

Does the div have an id attribute? If you you could use:

```
document.getElementById('id-of-div').appendChild(iframe);
```

Does this help?

Comment: I just figured the same thing - no, there's no way of knowing container ID or class as it could even be added in e.g. a blog post. I guess will have to use method A. Thanks for the reply